# Is there any use of a quadratic equation of state in FLRW cosmology?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, cosmology, pressure

Consider standard FLRW cosmology.  Usually, the relation between energy density $\rho$ and pressure $p$ of a cosmological fluid component is *linear*:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
p = w \, \rho,
\end{equation}
where $w$ is just a constant ($w = 0$ for the *dust model*, $w = \frac{1}{3}$ for *ultra-relativistic radiation*, $w = - 1$ for the *cosmological constant*, etc).  I'm interested in applications of the following non-linear equation of state (quadratic in this case):
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
p = -\, \kappa \, \rho^2,
\end{equation}
where $\kappa$ is a positive constant.  I never saw any textbook or paper discussing such an equation of state.  Is there a reason for that?  I would like to find some references on it.

Notice that there is no *sound speed* from (2) and that the four main *energy conditions* may be violated, depending on the value of the energy density $\rho$ relative to the constant $\kappa$:
\begin{align}
&\textsf{NEC:} \qquad \rho + p \ge 0. \tag{3} \\[12pt]
&\textsf{WEC:} \qquad \rho \ge 0, \quad \text{and} \quad \rho + p \ge 0. \tag{4} \\[12pt]
&\textsf{SEC:} \qquad \rho + 3 p \ge 0, \quad \text{and} \quad \rho + p \ge 0. \tag{5} \\[12pt]
&\textsf{DEC:} \qquad \rho \ge |\, p \,|. \tag{6}
\end{align}
These energy conditions are a subject of much controversy today, and nothing in physics imposes that they need to be satisfied in all cases.

The state equation (2) describes *phantom energy* when $\rho > 1/\kappa$ and may lead to a *Big Rip* scenario.

Local conservation of energy-momentum imposes the following constraint:
\begin{equation}\tag{7}
\nabla_{\mu} \, T^{\mu \nu} = 0 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \dot{\rho} \, a + 3 \, (\rho + p) \, \dot{a} = 0.
\end{equation}
Substituting (2) into (7) gives the energy density as a function of the scale factor $a(t)$:
\begin{equation}\tag{8}
\rho = \frac{\mu}{\mu \kappa + a^3} = \frac{\rho_0}{\kappa \, \rho_0 + (1 - \kappa \, \rho_0)(a / a_0)^3},
\end{equation}
where $\mu$ is an integration constant and $\rho_0$ is the energy density today (at time $t_0$ for which $a(t_0) \equiv a_0$).  Notice that (8) gives $\rho \approx 1 / \kappa = \text{cste}$ (the fluid is behaving like a cosmological constant) when $a / a_0 \ll 1$, and $\rho \propto a^{-3}$ (like *dust*) when $a / a_0 \gg 1$ (but only if $\kappa \, \rho_0 < 1$, so that energy density stay positive: $\rho > 0$).  So (2) may be a model for *inflation* before a matter (i.e. dust) era.

So was the equation of state (2) already discussed before (surely!)?  Any reference on it?

---

**EDIT:** Here's a cool graph made with *Mathematica*, of the evolution of the scale factor $a(t)/a_0$ for a model containing a cosmological constant ($\Lambda > 0$) and a fluid described by equation of state (2) (with $\kappa$ very small).  For the parameters selected, the universe is spatially *closed* ($k = 1$), and there's a *Big Bounce* without any singularity (no *Big Bang* and no *Big Rip*).  There's a timid *inflation* era, a *matter domination* era and a *Dark energy* era (second inflation):

[image]

Comment: Perhaps start here: https://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/astro-ph/0512224

Comment: This question is related to this one: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/452016/could-the-cosmic-fluid-be-better-described-as-a-kind-of-van-der-waals-gas-or-a